# How to determine which parameter I should linearize?

Tags: pde

Assumed I have the following equations with the parameters $\vec{A}(z, t)$, $\vec{B}(z, t)$ and the constants $a,\,b,\,c$:
$$
\begin{split}
\partial_tA&=a\partial_zA\\
\partial_tB&=b\partial_zB+A\cdot B\cdot c
\end{split}
$$
Now the usual approach is to split the equations for an implicit scheme like 
$$
\left(\frac{1}{dt}-\frac{\partial_z}{2}\right)A_1=\left(\frac{1}{dt}+a\frac{\partial_z}{2}\right)A_0
$$
which then can be solved. 
The split is done using
$$\begin{split}
\frac{A_1-A_0}{dt}&=\partial_tA\\
\partial_zA&=\frac{\partial_zA_1+\partial_zA_0}{2}\\
\frac{A_1-A_0}{dt}&=a\frac{\partial_zA_1+\partial_zA_0}{2}\\
\left(\frac{A_1}{dt}-a\frac{\partial_zA_1}{2}\right)&=\left(\frac{A_0}{dt}+\frac{a\partial_zA_0}{2}\right)\\
\left(\frac{1}{dt}-a\frac{\partial_z}{2}\right)A_1&=\left(\frac{1}{dt}+\frac{a\partial_z}{2}\right)A_0
\end{split}$$

For the equation system above I can then write (without the second term in the second equation):
$$\begin{split}
C&=\begin{pmatrix}
A\\B\end{pmatrix}\\
e&=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\b\end{pmatrix}\\
d&=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
\left(\frac{1}{dt}-e\partial_z-\frac{d}{2}\right)C_1&=\left(\frac{1}{dt}+e\partial_z+\frac{d}{2}\right)C_0\end{split}$$
But when including the second term, I can choose between
$$d=\begin{pmatrix}B_0\cdot c\\0
\end{pmatrix}$$
or 
$$d=\begin{pmatrix}0\\A_0\cdot c
\end{pmatrix}$$
depending on how I calculate
$$A\cdot B\cdot c$$
Is there a method to determine which $d$ I should use?

Comment: Your second equation is wrong: it should not contain $\partial_z A_0$ on the right hand side. The same is true for the equation for $C$ further down below.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Why should it not contain $\partial_zA_0$ on that side?

Comment: Because it was not a consistent discretization of the time derivative. But I see now that you added a factor of 1/2, which leads to the Crank-Nicolson scheme, and this is now correct.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake I did not see...